# My app does not change orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation

I am using XCode 4.6 and iOS 6.1. But  my app does not change orientation. I have set my app to support orientation in pList and added orientation change method. But still the app does not change orientation.

[image]

[image]

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);

}
```

I'm using TabBarController, and I'm adding it by using this code.

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabController;
```

In iOS 6 simulator all working fine but for iOS 5 it does not work.

Comment: What is your view setup!? Do you use a rootViewController? Is it a single controller, or a tabbar, or a navbar? No one can answer this question without these informations.

Comment: Appdelegate are u set the   self.window.rootViewController = YourController;

Comment: just comment that shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation mehtod and run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using tabBar so put this code in your AppDelegate at the bottom of @end.

```
@implementation UITabBarController (Rotation)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{   
    if ([self.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UIViewController *rootController = [((UINavigationController *)self.selectedViewController).viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        return [rootController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
    }
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
}

@end
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

**Code for Checking Orientation Working or Not ?**

Code ::

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
    ......
}
```

Check Method ::

```
-(void)orientationChanged {

   NSLog(@"Orientation Changed..!!");
}
```

**Code for Orientation Changed Methods**

In PCH File,

```
#define IOS_OLDER_THAN_6        ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] < 6.0 )
#define IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6 ( [ [ [ UIDevice currentDevice ] systemVersion ] floatValue ] >= 6.0 )
```

In .m file,

```
//For Less than IOS 6

#ifdef IOS_OLDER_THAN_6
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
   return toInterfaceOrientation;
}
#endif

// For Newer than IOS 6.
#ifdef IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   return YES;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
#endif
```

Hopefully, it'll be help to you.

Thanks.

Comment: Still Not changing orientation

Comment: First applied for that code & check whether orientation is working or not by getting response in NSLog()?

Comment: log value displaying fine but orientation not changing

Comment: This mthods are never called. i had pu log in it and it does not showed

Comment: In ios 6 simulator all working fine but for ios5 it does not work

Comment: the method for detecting change of orientation is helpfull +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to use these two new methods in order to control and configure the orientation changes for your viewControllers :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;    
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {    
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | 
            UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

The method you are implementing is for iOS 5.x , but the methods mentioned in this answer are for iOS 6.x. If you want compatibility for both the OS versions, then you need to implement both the methods in your viewController.

Comment: No still not changing orientation

Answer (score 0):

In your topmost navigation controller, define:

`-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {return [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];}`

and in your next viewController:

`-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {return YES;}`

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {  
return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | 
        UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```